# Streaming audio inside a call sended from code in android

Tags: java, android

Well, i want to call from my code and when the other persons answered my call send a audio clip in the audio streaming, i was ready is possible but also that isnt, help please.-

Answer (score 1):

So, multiple questions in one. I'll answer all of them, mostly so you can get the keywords you can search for.

1. Setting up a call programatically, perfectly possible and quite easy
2. Playing an audio file into the call, not so trivial. Using the Java API for Android, you just can't do it. Anyhow, you can create a C application which can play an audio file, use it in your Android app (NKD and JNI required here), and give it control of the microphone.

If you are comfortable using C and think you can learn how to use NDK and JNI, you can do it. If you're gonna need it to be done using Java... right now you will just not be able to do it.

pd: if you are thinking about playing a file in the speaker and hope it to get into the microphone, it won't work on most of the devices out there. There are quite good echo cancellation chips out there.

Comment: Thanks, i will read about NDK and JNI, i must writte the code in 5 days XD. But i know a little bite of C. Thanks Bro!.

Comment: Having no previous experience, 5 days seems like a pretty tight deadline. Good luck!

Comment: any clue on how to cancel the echo cancellation using JNI?